# jQuery multiple file upload plugin

Tags: java, jquery, file-upload

i am using the multiple file upload plugin using jQuery: http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/
the Upload handler provided in this plugin is in php. Is there and upload handler with similar features in java/j2ee ? Please let me know in case any one has used it earlier

Comment: Did you check the GAE version ? https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Google-App-Engine-Java ... it's JAVA !

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://swfupload.org/ maybe it will be useful 4 u :)

Answer (score 1):

try this,

https://github.com/valums/ajax-upload

It has multiple file upload support for old browsers too

Answer (score 0):

You could try jQuery uploadify
http://www.uploadify.com/